# Rails 6 running on Docker with bundler -v 2.0.2 installed... You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, bundler

I'm adding a new Rails 6 / Ruby 2.6 / Postgres app to Docker, however whenever I try to run a rake command (eg. `docker-compose run web rake db:setup`)  within the container, I get:

`You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.`

I've tried explicitly installing Bundler 2.0.2 within the container, however no luck.

Running within the Rails container, bundler-v returns 2.0.2,

```
root@114f7d6a2b72:/app# bundler -v
Bundler version 2.0.2
```

Within the Gemfile.lock:

```
RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.0p-1

BUNDLED WITH
   2.0.2
```

And within the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.0
...more stuff...
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN gem install bundler -v 2.0.2
RUN bundle install --verbose --jobs 20 --retry 5
```

This seems *so* simple, and yet I can't get it to work. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding after bundle installing?

Comment: this link might help https://shivab.com/blog/docker/2019/01/15/dockerization-of-rails-6-app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [Docs](https://bundler.io/guides/bundler_2_upgrade.html), you must run `gem update --system` to upgrade the `bundel` and I suggest also to use `ruby:2.6.1`